# What statistical test is for two tables consisting same set of IDs each of which has a group of dichotomous measures?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binary-data

What statistical test is for two tables consisting same set of IDs each of which has a group of dichotomous measures?

I have two tables as below:

Table A

```
 V1  V2  V3 ...... V20
```

ID01   1   1  0 .......  1

ID02   0   1  0 .......  1

ID03   1   0  0 .......  1
.......

ID99   1   1  0 .......  1

Table B

```
 V1  V2  V3 ...... V20
```

ID01   0   0  0 .......  1

ID02   1   1  0 .......  1

ID03   0   0  1 .......  0
.......

ID99   1   1  0 .......  0

Basically, two tables have the same set of 100 IDs.
Each column is a measure of a given test, as 1 or 0. The value 1 or 0 are dichotomous outcome, no other values.

I need compare how close (correlated) between table A and B. What statistical test should I use? Neither table is defined as standard/correct, I need to know the similar the two tables are.

Edit with more info (and answer comment by @nxglogic):
A method is developed, and is tested with 100 IDs twice (table A for the first test and B for the second). The method generates binary outputs for each measurement (V1, V2, ..., V20). At the moment, V1 to V20 are treated with the same weight (meaning they are equally important to evaluate the method).

Extended question: if the binary value (dichotomous) are actually numeric like 12, 34.56, etc, what testing should I use?

Thnaks!

Comment: Since table B is for the same ID's, add that data to the right of table A in the same order for ID.  Then see which tests are correlated via all possible pairs of variables, as some may be noise with no association.  Tanimoto distance is ideal for comparing binary vectors (features).  If your data were normally-distributed, multivariate "canonical correlation analysis" allows to compare correlation between 2 sets of features.   Data mining would first ask, "which features separate the two tables?", since one would not usually assume all the features are informative.

Comment: @nxglogic See Edit in the post:
A method is developed, and is tested with 100 IDs twice (table A for the first test and B for the second). The method generates binary outputs for each measurement (V1, V2, ..., V20). At the moment, V1 to V20 are treated with the same weight (meaning they are equally important to evaluate the method). Thanks!